# install swipl using docker

Tags: docker, swi-prolog

I want to build an app using swipl+bash+node.js.

I *think* that I want to use Docker (to avoid pathname issues).

Trying to apt-get install swipl with a simple script fails (at the interactive input stage (Geographic location)):

---

### Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN   apt-get update && \
 printf 'Y\n2\n' | apt-get install swi-prolog

RUN   export PATH=/root/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/root/.local/bin:$PATH

COPY hello.pl ./
ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/bin/swipl -g 'consult("hello.pl").' -g 'hello.' -g 'halt.'
```

---

### hello.pl

```
hello:-
    format("Hello from SWIPL",[]).
```

Comment: What's the actual prompt?  Is it what's shown in [how can i pass arguments or bypass it in docker build process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53079135/how-can-i-pass-arguments-or-bypass-it-in-docker-build-process), and if so, does the recommended solution of setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` help?

Comment: ``` 
=> => # questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing
=> => # the time zones in which they are located.
=> => #   1. Africa      4. Australia  7. Atlantic  10. Pacific  13. Etc
=> => #   2. America     5. Arctic     8. Europe    11. SystemV
=> => #   3. Antarctica  6. Asia       9. Indian    12. US 
=> => # Geographic area: 
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, David Maze's suggestion helped.

For the record, the finished versions are:

---

### Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

## for apt to be noninteractive
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN true

## preseed tzdata, update package index, upgrade packages and install needed software
RUN echo "tzdata tzdata/Areas select America" > /tmp/preseed.txt ; \
    echo "tzdata tzdata/Zones/America select Toronto" >> /tmp/preseed.txt; \
    debconf-set-selections /tmp/preseed.txt && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y tzdata
    
RUN   apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y swi-prolog

RUN   export PATH=/root/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/root/.local/bin:$PATH
COPY hello.pl ./
ENTRYPOINT swipl -g 'consult("hello.pl").' -g 'hello.' -g 'halt.'

# docker build . --tag hellofromswipl
# docker run hellofromswipl
```

---

### hello.pl

```
    get_time(T),
    format_time(user_output,'Hello from SWIPL %a, %d %b %Y %T GMT', T).
```